# Trying to reference a .NET 4.6.1 class library from a .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Screenshots => https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4FwD.jpg

I'm trying to reference a .NET 4.6.1 Class library in a .NET Core 1.0.0 project. It's added to references but whenever I try to include the "using" statement in a controller I get "the type or namespace could not be found error."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can either only target .NET 4.6.1, and that way you would not support .net core. Or you can add `#if NET461` directives in your code, and that way it will be able to find the type and namespace in the if.

your problem is that the code is unsupported in .net core, and therefore cannot build for .net core

Answer (score 0):

You need to set .NET 4.6.1 as the framework for the project. In your project.json, replace the "frameworks"-section with:

```
"frameworks": 
{
   "net461": {}
}
```

Comment: I have the solution set up to accept both frameworks, here is my project.json file:

https://lockin.in/sub/share.php?shareid=32bd9efef4a051663310a2b220b7d625e8326caea5e2ee12bb31376b4ec00c559f57561e1ee0885ac0bb0003637798125127c1d0840cd1f8278b63c7f37ac769&type=1

Comment: Try removing "netcoreapp1.0" from it the "frameworks"-section and see if the project builds. You should still be able to build your project using dotnet.exe and host it using kestrel, even without the "netcoreapp1.0" framework in the project.json file.